# Coordinate offset between MainActivity and Custom View

Tags: java, android, graphics, coordinates

In my application, I draw certain graphics using the Canvas object in the MainActivity class. After that when a user swipes on the screen, I use a Custom View to draw horizontal and vertical lines over the previously created graphics.

The problem is that there is slight coordinate offset between the MainActivity and the CustomView. Due to this my lines are not in accordance with other graphic objects on the game. To confirm this, I made the following call from the MainActivity and my CustomView class:

canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 50, 50, paint);

The result was two parallel lines. The origin for the CustomView lies at the top right corner of the phone where there was a certain offset for the origin of the MainActivity class.

(Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3BDK.png )

I would be grateful if someone could point out on what could be the issue here.

Following are the relevant files:

***activity_main.xml***

```
<com.example.offsettest.CustomLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/customLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">
</com.example.offsettest.CustomLayout>
```

***MainActivity.java***

```
package com.example.offsettest;

import com.rgtech.offsettest.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Paint paint;
    private CustomLayout customLayout; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        draw();
    }

    public void draw(){
        DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        float width = metrics.widthPixels;
        float height = metrics.heightPixels;
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) width, (int) height, Config.RGB_565);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        mCanvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        customLayout = (CustomLayout) findViewById(R.id.customLayout);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        customLayout.addView(imageView);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mCanvas.drawLine(0, 0, 50, 50, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

***CustomLayout.java***

```
package com.example.offsettest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")

    public class CustomLayout extends LinearLayout{
        private Paint paint = new Paint();
        public CustomLayout(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }
        public CustomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }
        public CustomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        }
        @Override
        public void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setDither(true);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 50, 50, paint);
        }
    }
```

In addition to these files, I only set android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" in the Manifest file.

Comment: It would be easier to visualize if you posted the code snippets in question, including the layout xml for MainActivity.

Comment: @JustinPowell Thanks for your inputs. I have added the relevant code snippet. My mxml just contains the custom view. It would be great if you could provide some pointers on what could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this is to remove the padding or margin of the image view or of the root view of the layout. (If there is any)
Another possibility is to calculate the offset/distance between their left-top-corner positions using `view.getX()` respectively `view.getRawX()` (and for Y as well) and then draw your lines not at `(0, 0, 50, 50)` but at `(offsetX, offsetY, 50 + offsetX, 50 + offsetY)`.

EDIT: I played around with this code a little bit and then noticed that calling `imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);` solves the problem.
Your draw method in MainActivity.java should now look like this:

```
public void draw() {

    DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float width = metrics.widthPixels;
    float height = metrics.heightPixels;

    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) width, (int) height, Config.RGB_565);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    mCanvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    customLayout = (CustomLayout) findViewById(R.id.customLayout);
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true); // call this method
    customLayout.addView(imageView);

    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mCanvas.drawLine(0, 0, 50, 50, paint);
}
```

Comment: Setting the padding and margin did not help. In my MainActivity file, in the onTouchEvent I compared event.getX(), event.getRawX() (and Y as well) and the values were same.I have created a new project removing all other additional functions and just drawing the two lines in my screenshot. The offset problem still persists. I have added code for all the files in my original post.

Comment: I looked into offset piece that you had mentioned. So there is no difference in Y and Raw Y inside OnTouch() method. But inside OnTouchEvent() method, though the X and RawX values are same,  I get a difference of 38 between rawY and Y values (i.e. rawY – Y = 38). But just adjusting for this offset doesn’t fix the issue. Also, the canvas that I create in my MainActivity class has a height of 800 whereas the canvas passed to the dispatchDraw() method in custom view has a height of 762 (again a difference of 38).  Please let me know possible areas to look into to remove this offset.

Comment: Additionally, I observed the Y offset between lines drawn from the  MainActivity and Custom View class increases as the Y value increases. I tried the set of following calls both from the Main Activity and my Custom View.  
   mCanvas.drawLine(0.0f, 100.0f, 200.0f, 100.0f, paint);
   mCanvas.drawLine(0.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f, paint); 
   …
   mCanvas.drawLine(0.0f, 200.0f, 600.0f, 600.0f, paint); ..

The two lines drawn for Y=600 were much farther apart than the lines drawn for Y = 100. 
Screenshot: http://oi59.tinypic.com/qyzf39.jpg

Comment: I realize that this can be solved if I apply a coordinate transformation for x and y values and get corresponding values in my custom view for given x and y values in MainActivity. But the problem is that the offset is different on different phones and I can't really come up with a generic formula to compute the transformed x and y values. I think I am missing something fundamental here. There should be some way in which I can enforce that X and Y values in my MainActivity match the values in my Custom View. I would be really grateful if somebody could provide some pointers on this.